# MDX adding together two cube measures across two role playing dimensions

Tags: mdx, olap, aggregation, olap-cube, cross-join

I have two queries which I would like to join together,which would give me the calculated total of the row. The problem I have is that although the measures are from 1 fact table the Squad names are in two role playing dimensions. I'm extremely new to MDX.

The outcome would be something like

```
 | Competition    | Squad   | Goals A | Goals B | Total (Goals A + Goals B)|
 |----------------|---------|---------|---------|--------------------------|
 | Premier League | Arsenal | 25      | 15      | 40                       |
```

Thanks in advance.

Query1:

```
SELECT 
([Measures].[Goals A]) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ([Dim Competition].[Hierarchy].[Competition ID],[Squad A].[Squad Name].ALLMEMBERS) ON ROWS
FROM 
[FDC Star]
WHERE [Dim Competition].[Competition ID].&[1];
```

Query1 result:

```
Competition     Squad                 Goals A
Premier League  Arsenal                 25
Premier League  Aston Villa              8
Premier League  Chelsea                 22
Premier League  Everton                 17
Premier League  Fulham                  17
Premier League  Liverpool               17
Premier League  Manchester City         25
Premier League  Manchester United       28
Premier League  Newcastle United        13
Premier League  Norwich City            13
Premier League  Queens Park Rangers      8
Premier League  Reading                 15
Premier League  Southampton             15
Premier League  Stoke City              14
Premier League  Sunderland              11
Premier League  Swansea City            19
Premier League  Tottenham Hotspur       17
Premier League  West Bromwich Albion    17
Premier League  West Ham United         19
```

Query2:

```
SELECT 
([Measures].[Goals B]) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ([Dim Competition].[Hierarchy].[Competition ID],[Squad B].[Squad Name].ALLMEMBERS) ON ROWS
FROM 
[FDC Star]
WHERE [Dim Competition].[Competition ID].&[1];
```

Query2 result:

```
Competition     Squad                 Goals B
Premier League  Arsenal                 15
Premier League  Aston Villa              9
Premier League  Chelsea                 17
Premier League  Everton                 18
Premier League  Fulham                  15
Premier League  Liverpool               17
Premier League  Manchester City         16
Premier League  Manchester United       26
Premier League  Newcastle United        14
Premier League  Norwich City            11
Premier League  Queens Park Rangers      9
Premier League  Reading                  8
Premier League  Southampton             12
Premier League  Stoke City               7
Premier League  Sunderland              10
Premier League  Swansea City            12
Premier League  Tottenham Hotspur       22
Premier League  West Bromwich Albion    12
Premier League  West Ham United         5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending many hours trying to come up with a solution I have finally solved my query.

Thanks

```
    WITH  
    MEMBER [Measures].[GFA] AS 
    (
    ([Measures].[Goals A]),
    linkmember([Dim Squad].[Squad Name],[Squad A].[Squad Name]),
    root([Squad Name])
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[GFB] AS 
    (
    ([Measures].[Goals B]),
    linkmember([Dim Squad].[Squad Name],[Squad B].[Squad Name]),
    root([Squad Name])
    )
    MEMBER [MEASURES].[GF] AS
    (
        [Measures].[GFA] + [Measures].[GFB]
    )
    select 
    {[Measures].[GFA],[Measures].[GFB],[MEASURES].[GF]} on 0,
    non empty [Dim Squad].[Squad Name].allmembers on 1
    from [FDC Star]
    where [Dim Competition].[Competition ID].&[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Goals B Linked]
AS (LinkMember([Squad A].[Squad Name].CurrentMember, [Squad B].[Squad Name]), [Measures].[Goals B]),
MEMBER [Measures].[Total]
AS [Measures].[Goals A] + [Measures].[Goals B Linked]

SELECT 
{[Measures].[Goals A], [Measures].[Goals B Linked], [Measures].[Total]}  ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ([Dim Competition].[Hierarchy].[Competition ID],[Squad A].[Squad Name].ALLMEMBERS) ON ROWS
FROM 
[FDC Star]
WHERE [Dim Competition].[Competition ID].&[1];
```